# AutoMapperMappingException with source type System.Object

Tags: c#, azure-functions, automapper

I register Automapper as below:

```
builder.RegisterAutoMapper(config => config.AllowNullCollections = true, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

I try to map as follows:

```
mapper.Map<'destination-contract'>(source-object);
```

in case my profile was missing, i have following exception message:
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
**System.Object -> 'destination-contract'**

Why is the source type System.Object, while I specified the source type in the mapping profile?

Anyone any idea?

thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem. I do not understand

Comment: Because the overload you're using takes `object`. This was already changed to always show the type at runtime. That might be confusing too in some circumstances.

Comment: Already found the issue, the Map-overload with the TSource did solve the confusing thing !